# stop scipy fsolve or hybrd immediately when the tolerance is reached

Tags: python, scipy

I am dealing with a time-­consuming optimization problem where each function evaluation takes about 20 minutes, and I have to perform the optimization for several parameters. Therefore, I would like to terminate the scipy fsolve or hybrd immediately when the maximum of the function return values are smaller than a certain criterion, e.g. 1.e­-6, to avoid further calculation of the jacobians. Since the scipy fsolve and hybrd do not support the callback argument, I wonder if there are other ways that I can terminate the optimization process without throwing errors?

Thank you.
Tsung­Han

Comment: Be more precise about your exact criteria's. It's also questionable to use those methods incl. num-diff for such slow function-evals in my opinion.

Comment: For the criteria, I choose the maximum of the function return vector to be smaller than a certain value, for example, max(fun(x))<1.e-6, and the solution should be the x. Right now, I can solve the problem by printing the solution x to the hard drive, and then raise an error when max(fun(x))<1.e-6. But this method forces the program to stop abnormally when the criterion is satisfied. Therefore, I wonder if there are other elegant ways to solve this problem.